# Ruby reserve word error while saving object

Tags: activerecord, attributes

I have a table Radcheck with 'attribute' as one of the column. Using safe_attribute gem I am able to write and read column values but while saving the object I get following error.

```
Radcheck.new  
x = Radcheck.new  
x.send(:write_attribute, :attribute, 'aa')   
x.send(:read_attribute, :attribute, 'aa')                    
x.save
```

Log of error while saving object

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:141:in `attribute'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activemodel-3.1.3/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:143:in `attribute_change'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activemodel-3.1.3/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:117:in `block in changes'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activemodel-3.1.3/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:117:in `map'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activemodel-3.1.3/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:117:in `changes'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:23:in `save'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in save'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block in save'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:252:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
from (irb):46
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'ruby-1.9.3-p0 :047 >
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi friend I think no problem related to safe_attributes gem.

```
Radcheck.new  
x = Radcheck.new  
x.send(:write_attribute, :attribute, 'aa')   
#read_attribute does not requires any value
#x.send(:read_attribute, :attribute, 'aa') 
x.send(:read_attribute, :attribute)                
x.save
```

You can also call the real_attribute,write_attribute directly on the active record object.

```
Radcheck.new  
x = Radcheck.new  
x.write_attribute(:attribute, 'aa')
x.read_attribute(:attribute)              
x.save
```

[Visit safe attributes](https://github.com/bjones/safe_attributes#readme)

Also ensure the following in your model.

```
class Radcheck < ActiveRecord::Base
  bad_attribute_names :attribute
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i have followed the safe_attribute documentation. But still getting the same error. I am working on ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.1 (Safe Attribute is tested on 1.9.2, 1.8.7)